# Does Killing entire app state or restarting it cancels Firestore pending write?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to cancel a firestore write process on 60-second timeout, it is not possible to cancel a pending write in firestore, so I'm thinking about killing the app state or restarting it entirely, is that going to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If disk persistence is enabled (as it is by default on Android and iOS devices) the pending writes are persisted to disk, and will survive app restarts.

Comment: so, there is no way to cancel the pending write?

Comment: this is a basic right of a developer, please add it.

Comment: To cancel pending writes you can call `clearPersistence`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#clearpersistence.